# how to pass class value in a variable using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have jQuery code where i am trying to put a class values in a variable & then trying to use that variable value in if else condition & comparing with static value 'FCL' But that's not working.class name is 'kuuj' & this class value can be (LCL,FCL,BULK,AIR) Only.

```js
var xxssees = $('.kuuj').val();
if(xxssees == "FCL")
{
$('#sonal').html(xxssees); 
}
else 
{
   $('#sonal').html('hello'); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>Solution : </strong><label id="sonal" style="color:Green"></label><br />
```

Comment: val() is only applicable for an input element. Can you add the html for class kuuj

Comment: if you want to call class name , you need to get that class's parent element

Comment: the issue is the class kuuj value is not passed in to the xxssees variable.i want to pass class value & then need to use in if else condition if variable value is equals to "FCL" bcz i have to use it furture.this all is dynamic & class value calculated after some calculations. but the class values can be only either LCL or FCL or AIR or BULK. so if you can make this working by making adding/changing some code ther then please do this,by using theat class values only. Regards- Ankit

Comment: @Ankit  check answers below. Either your html is wrong or your code have some issue.You will get answer of both below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.`val() is only applicable for an input element` and then your code will work fine.check below:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var xxssees = $('.kuuj').val();
  if(xxssees == "FCL"){
     $('#sonal').text(xxssees);  
  }else {
     $('#sonal').text('hello');  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>Solution : </strong><label id="sonal" style="color:Green"></label><br />

<input class="kuuj" value = "FCLs">
```

2.If `kuju` class is on any other element apart from input then use `.text()` or `.html()` to get the value. Check below:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var xxssees = $('.kuuj').html();  // you can use .text() also
  if(xxssees == "FCL"){
      $('#sonal').html(xxssees);  //you can use .text() also
  }else {
      $('#sonal').html('hello');  //you can use .text() also
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>Solution : </strong><label id="sonal" style="color:Green"></label><br />

<div class="kuuj">FCLs</div>
```

Comment: yes thank you so much sir its working now. thanks alot sir  .Regards - Ankit

Answer (score 0):

You need to add input field rather then label

Instead of

```
<label id="sonal" style="color:Green"></label>
```

You add

```
 <input type="text" id="sonal" value="" />
```

feel free to ask if required further help

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var xxssees = $('.kuuj').val();
  console.log(xxssees);
  if(xxssees == "FCL"){
     $('#sonal').html(xxssees);  
  }else {
     $('#sonal').html('hello');  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>Solution : </strong><label id="sonal" style="color:Green"></label><br />

<input type="hidden" class="kuuj" value = "FCL">
```